# Conditionally apply a CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, conditional-statements

I have a style defined that needs to be applied **only** if there is an icon, but not if there isn't.

The html structure with an icon is as follows:

```
<li class="g-menu-item g-menu-item-226 g-menu-item-type-component g-standard">
  <a class="g-menu-item-container" href="/en/services/visas">
    <i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i>
    <span class="g-menu-item-content">
      <span class="g-menu-item-title">Visas</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The structure without an icon is as follows:

```
<li class="g-menu-item g-menu-item-232 g-menu-item-type-component g-standard">
  <a class="g-menu-item-container" href="/en/destinations/australia/adelaide">
    <span class="g-menu-item-content">
      <span class="g-menu-item-title">Adelaide</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The SCSS I have worked fine on items with an icon. It moves the span with the class `g-menu-item-title` to the right by 1.25rem and up by 1rem:

```
.aside-nav {
  .g-menu-item-container {
    .g-menu-item-content {
      margin-left: 1.25rem !important;
      margin-top: -1rem !important;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when there is no icon, it makes the menu items in the sidebar squished into each other.

How do I change this SCSS so that it only applies to menu items in the aside where the item has an icon, but not when there isn't an icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors),

It'll let you target an element that is next to another element:

```css
i + .g-menu-item-content {
   margin-left: 1.25rem !important;
   margin-top: -1rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
<li class="g-menu-item g-menu-item-232 g-menu-item-type-component g-standard">
  <a class="g-menu-item-container" href="/en/destinations/australia/adelaide">
    <span class="g-menu-item-content">
      <span class="g-menu-item-title">Adelaide</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="g-menu-item g-menu-item-226 g-menu-item-type-component g-standard">
  <a class="g-menu-item-container" href="/en/services/visas">
    <i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i>
    <span class="g-menu-item-content">
      <span class="g-menu-item-title">Visas</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @nitsan, that's perfect, thank you.